# IFRAME in MSFT CRM for Outlook

Tags: iframe, outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

If an IFRAME is added to a form in CRM, will it display in Outlook?

The confusion I have is with the following phrase:

Web resources and IFRAMEs aren’t displayed using the CRM for Outlook reading pane or CRM for tablets.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328034.aspx

(What does it mean by the Outlook reading frame?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading pane is what displays within the Outlook application window itself. It is invoked by selecting a record in the grid view - much like selecting an email in your inbox without explicitly opening it.

See item 1 on this post for a screenshot of the reading pane: http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2010/11/top-ten-reasons-crm-for-outlook-is-the-premier-user-experience-for-crm-2011.html. It works the same for CRM 2011 and 2013.

However, if you double-click (or otherwise open) a CRM record from within Outlook then it will open a new window which displays the same interface you would see if you were to open the same record in the browser (again, much like opening an email in your box). This popup window is where the IFRAME would be supported.

Comment: Thanks! The article also indicates that the reading pane preview can be diaabled for an entity. This article also helps explain some other points I didn't realize.

Comment: You can change the Outlook preview/reading pane availability in the respective CRM entity customization screen. It's under the "Outlook & Mobile" section at the very bottom of the entity definition.